# Accessing the output of Matlab help command

Tags: matlab

I am working for a Readme generator script for several functions written in Matlab. For this, I need to write the output produced by the command

```
help <function_name>
```

to the Readme file. I am looking for a way to to access the output as string and store it to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `help` function returns the displayed text. Example:

```
text = help('help');
disp(help)
text =

  HELP Display help text in Command Window.
     HELP, by itself, lists all primary help topics. Each primary topic
     corresponds to a folder name on the MATLAB search path....
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just what I needed.